# Updating single char of string

Tags: c, string, pointers

How do I update a single `char` in a string declared as `char*`?

I have tried this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char* s = "hello";
    s[0] = 'y';
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles without warnings or errors with GCC 4.8.1 (MinGW) using these parameters:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o str.exe str.c
```

But when I run the application, it only prints a blank line?

Comment: https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/

Comment: Change `char *s` to `const char *s` and the compiler will warn, it's worth noting that as it is, `s` points to a string literal which is inherently `const`.

Comment: The reason behind this is `char *s = "hello";` creates a *string-literal* in the `readonly` data segment. Attempt to change readonly data -> bad things happen.

Comment: I worship mjolnir.....

Comment: @iharob actually, it didn't throw me any warnings or errors. It still compiles just fine with `s` declared as `const char*`.

Comment: Enable warnings `-Wall -Werror` would do it!

Comment: @iharob Hmm, no. As you might see in the OP, I compile it with exactly the parameters you mention, and still no compiler messages. I dunno, maybe these warnings you mention were added/removed in a certain version?

Comment: @user966939 Interesting, I will test it with my *gcc-5.1* when I get some free time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is an attempt to modify a string literal. It results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Related, from the standard `C11`, chapter §6.4.5, *String literals*

> [..] If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

You need to use an array of `char`s if you want to modify the contents, instead. Something along the line of

```
char s[] = "hello";
```

Otherwise, if you want to have the `char *s` form, you have to

1. Allocate memory to `s`
2. Use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy the content into `s`

and then, you can modify `s`, as the memory location returned by `malloc()` will be writable.

Comment: Right.  Declare s like this:  char s[] = "hello";

Comment: @bruceg actually you can leave the size out. Compiler will allocated appropriately.

Comment: Good point.  Your way is even better.  I updated my previous comment.